# Consume Web Api in react js

Tags: ios, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to consume Web Api in React Js,  its not connecting with it, but this Api working fine on Android Project, can you help me where is the issue or a better way to do it, i don't know about react js.. Here is the code which i am working.. 
It is basically for registering user

code to fetch API

```
 const createAccount = function(
    email,
    password,
    title,
    firstname,
    lastname,
    middlename,
    mobileno,
    businessname,
    abn,
    dob
) {
    //return fetch(`${Constants.baseURL}api/Thetaxfactor/Post`, {
        return fetch('http://webservice.thetaxfactorapp.com.au/api/TheTaxfactor/Post', {
        method: 'Get',
        headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
            //'Accept': 'application/json',
           // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: HttpUtil.toEncodedForm({
            email,
            password,
            title,
            firstname,
            lastname,
            middlename,
            mobileno: .isUndefined(mobileno) || .isNull(mobileno) || _.isNil(mobileno) || mobileno === "null" ? "" : mobileno,
            businessname,
            abn,
            dob,
        }),
    });
};
```

Code of onPress

```
onPress() {
// call getValue() to get the values of the form
const value = this.refs.form.getValue();
if (value) {
const title = value.title;
const firstname = value.firstName;
const middlename = _.isNull(value.middleName) ? '' : value.middleName;
const lastname = value.surname;
const businessname = _.isNull(value.businessName) ? '' : value.businessName;
const password = value.password;
const dob = moment(value.dateOfBirth).format(Constants.API_DATE_FORMAT);
const email = value.emailAddress;
const mobilenumber = value.mobileNumber;
const businessabn = _.isNull(value.businessABN) ? '' : value.businessABN;
this.setState({ loading: true });

Auth.createAccount(
email,
password,
title,
firstname,
lastname,
middlename,
mobilenumber,
businessname,
businessabn,
dob
)
.then(response => {
this.setState({ loading: false });
setTimeout(() => {
if (response.status !== 201) {
// could not login

Alert.alert(
'Cannot Create Account',
'Email address may already be in use, or password is too short (8 characters minimum)',
[
{
text: 'RETRY',
},
],
{
cancelable: true,
}
);
} else {
Alert.alert('Account Created', 'Log in to continue to the main menu');
this.props.navigation.goBack();
}
}, 250);
})
.catch(error => {
this.setState({ loading: false });
Alert.alert(
'Cannot Create Account',
'No internet connection available',
[
{
// 'No internet connection available', [{
text: 'OK',
},
],
{
cancelable: true,
}
);
});
}
}
```

Comment: SO ist not a code writing service. There are many ways to integrate an existing api into your react application and explaining the whole process is not in the scope of this site. If you don't know about react js you should first learn the basics yourself e.g. by following some tutorials. There are plenty of them that also cover fetching data from an api.

Comment: I am facing this issue..                                                                                                              NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <96E945C7-F4AC-4CE7-A1D4-87033FE03924>.<1>, NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask <96E945C7-F4AC-4CE7-A1D4-87033FE03924>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.thetaxfactor.com.au/rest/user/data/combined, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.thetaxfactor.com.au/rest/user/data/combined, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1} [-1001]

Comment: i have given this api 'http://webservice.thetaxfactorapp.com.au/api/TheTaxfactor/Post' but it is accepting this api 'api.thetaxfactor.com.au/rest/' no matter what i do

Comment: i am not asking for writing code just asking to guide or tell me what should be a problem, i am searching for 4  days continuously and then i have posted here as a last resort, but the problem is i have to work on this code as our react js developer is out of town for 12 days, and now its my responsibility to  finish the task.. I work in dot net and php but dont have knowledge in react js..

Comment: I see why you urgently need a solution and I am sorry for you. But most active members here are professionals too. You can't expect them to provide you the code that you get paid for (or debug it for you). From the code you have shown so far it is next to impossible to guide you to a solution (which again is not the scope of this site anyways). There are just too many details to consider that we can't know about. You may consult a paid code mentor for that purpose.

Comment: hmm ok thanks for reply.. and i  am sorry if I  offended you, l just didn't know how to write down problem ..and just wrote what came in mind when i asked a question

Comment: I'm not in any way offended. I would help you if I could. But as I said you likely need way more guidance than anybody can provide you given the information. What you provided so far is not sufficient. It will need a significant amount of time and effort to dig into your code to find the problem even if you provided full access to it. I'm afraid chances are very low to get a useful answer here. You need to further narrow down the problem first and you may find some useful help. Good luck.